# Using pygame and font.render, how do I make sure the text doesn't go across a certain boundary but instead move down?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame-surface

```
tutorialText = tutorialFont.render("""A sliding puzzle is a type of game where a player must 
            rearrange a set of pieces to complete an image by sliding the pieces into the empty space. 
            This game is a variation of a sliding puzzle, where you can click near the blank spot or use the 
            arrow keys to move blocks around. To solve the game, you must rearrange the letters to form words. 
            There are numbers at the bottom to guide you. To have solved a game, starting from the topmost 
            left block, the number will be 1, and reading from left to right the numbers will go in order go 
            all the way to the last column before going to the next row. 
            The blank block will be the bottom most right block.""", True, (255,255,255), (196, 164, 132)).
```

I have a lot of text, I don't want it to go over 200 pixels away from the starting position, which is (0,100), so no over (200,100), but instead go down.

I have tried searching online, but I haven't found anything yet.